# how to use refcursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, plsql-package

I am trying to run an explain plan using  a wrapper, but getting compilation error. Can you please help troubleshoot this error.

```
    set serveroutput on
    var my_cur refcursor;
    begin
    :my_cur:=sys.run_xplan('select * from hcc.Tab_A');
    end;
    /print my_cur
```

Error:

```
begin
:my_cur:=sys.run_xplan('select * from hcc.Tab_A');
end;
/print my_cur
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" when expecting one of the following:

( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
<an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
<a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
merge pipe purge
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Comment: The `print` just needs to be on a separate line. The `/` has to be on a line on its own.

Comment: yes, but also, there is no SYS.RUN_XPLAN ? Is there?

Comment: No, but people will insist on creating their objects in the sys schema... hard to guess if they've done that as a wrapper around `dbms_xplan`, or meant to call something in there directly, maybe.

Comment: Ugh, people will be WRONG! but yeah i was afraid of that @AlexPoole